# Jwplayer : Video loading error on the first attempt {firefox-22(Mac)}

Tags: firefox, jwplayer, jwplayer6

Using FF 22 on Mac, trying to run some videos using jwplayer.
Clicking on any video for the first time generates the attached error message. Then clicking on the error message or any other video runs the video normally.
Refreshing the page resets the problem into action and it is encountered again.

Jwplayer version: 6.4.3359

[image: Error Message]

The error is not encountered on other browsers or any earlier version of firefox. Any Suggestions?

Comment: The issue disappeared for the following two cases:
1) file path was given as http: while the webpage was https:, changing the file path to https: fixed the issue. 
2) when the videos were loaded from different domain.
`Test Case A: webpage: https://abc.com  File path: http://abc.com/vd.mp4 == Error`
`Test Case B: webpage: https://abc.com  File Path: http://beta.abc.com/vd.mp4 == No Error`

Comment: Disabling the cache, helped in replicating this issue on every click. It prevented the jwplayer.flash.swf to be cached.

Comment: Ah, ok. Glad you got it.